# How to Navigate another page when application launch first time in swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I am implementing an iOS app. when User Launch the application first time, I need to navigate to another page and from next time onwards I need to navigate Home Page. How to do this task in iOS swift?

Comment: Save bool value in UserDefault for first time or not. then write logic(if..else) in appDelegate, navigate to depended VC

Comment: Can You Share any required source code?

Comment: Add the code that you have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution to this common problem assumes that

1. At the outset — in this example, that's before the `"username"` key has been set in the user defaults — we want to launch to the storyboard's Initial View Controller (where the user is supposed to set the `"username"` key).
2. Thereafter, we always want to launch to a *different* view controller in the storyboard, whose identifier in this example is `"root"`.

It's very short and simple!

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        if let rvc = self.window?.rootViewController {
            if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:"username") as? String != nil {
                self.window!.rootViewController = rvc.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("root")
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**: if you get this error: "**Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'window'** ".

Answer is : you have to write your codes inside of SceneDelegate.swift

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard


    guard  let a=UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "wantOverview")  else {



        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
          let initialVc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstTimeViewController") as! firstTimeViewController
          self.window?.rootViewController = initialVc
          self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


          defaults.set(false, forKey: "wantOverview")
        return
      }


      let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let initialVc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
            self.window?.rootViewController = initialVc
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using userdefaults. Just make a new controller like SplashViewController which will only redirect to desired ViewController.

```
import UIKit

class SplashViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        decideWhichScreenToShow()
    }

    // This logic will do
    func decideWhichScreenToShow(){
        if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "your_key"){
            // This will execute first time, in that controller's viewDidLoad() make this true
        }else{

        }
    }
}
```

You can write same logic in Appdelegate.

Comment: You should remove the irrelevant method to be clearer : `didReceiveMemoryWarning()` `preferredStatusBarStyle` `prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden()`

Answer (score 0):

Create func for checking that if your key in UserDefaults or not using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40964844/7084910) & Then check by if...else

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    if isKeyPresentInUserDefaults(key: "isFirstTime") {
        let home = HomeVC()
        window?.rootViewController = home
    } else {
        let login = LoginVC()
        window?.rootViewController = login
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isFirstTime")
    }

    return true
}

func isKeyPresentInUserDefaults(key: String) -> Bool {
    return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) != nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use change the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in AppDelegate to achieve this.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    guard let firstTime = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "IsFirstTime")  else {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "IsFirstTime")
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "FirstStoryBoard", bundle: nil)
        let initialVc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstControllerId") as! FirstTimeViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialVc
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let initialVc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NormalInitialController") as! ViewController
    self.window?.rootViewController = initialVc
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true

}
```

You check if the value for key, "IsFirstTime", exists in UserDefaults. There won't be a value if the app is launching for the first time.
In this case, you can launch your FirstTimeViewController and set a value to the key in UserDefaults.

If a value exists in UserDefaults, just initiate your normal ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


    if firstTime = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "firstTime")
    {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SecondStoryBoard", bundle: nil)
        let MainView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondTimeViewController") as! SecondTimeViewController

        let navController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: MainView)

        self.window?.rootViewController = navController

    }
    else
    {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "firstTime")

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "FirstStoryBoard", bundle: nil)
        let MainView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstTimeViewController") as! FirstTimeViewController

        let navController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: MainView)

        self.window?.rootViewController = navController

    }

}
```